# Set-Execution policy on remote computer using Variable

Tags: powershell, execution

I have a problem reverting back powershell execution policy on remote computer using variable.

```
$RestrykcjaNowa = 'Bypass'
$RestrykcjaZastana = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Komputer -ScriptBlock { Get-ExecutionPolicy }
$RestrykcjaZastana
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Komputer -ScriptBlock { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy $RestrykcjaNowa -Scope LocalMachine -Force } | Out-Null
```

But I got an error

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ExecutionPolicy' because it is null

When I replace variable `$RestrykcjaNowa` with value *Bypass* in last command it goes smoothly.

I noticed that variable `$RestrykcjaZastana` is not displayed on the screen when called in 2nd line of the code and is of type *int* but i can't assign value *Bypass* to integer variable manually.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: The variable defined outside your script block is by default not available inside your script block. Use `$USING:RestrykcjaNowa` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues to address:

1. Execution policies are not strings; they are a separate enumerated type, `[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]`. You will have to assign them as such to your variable:

   ```
   $RestrykcjaNowa = [Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]::Bypass
   ```
2. Variables outside of scriptblocks need to be referenced from within the script block with `using:`:

   ```
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Komputer -ScriptBlock { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy $using:RestrykcjaNowa -Scope LocalMachine -Force } | Out-Null
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not evaluated when Scriptblock is defined.
However for your case, you may use below code with which you can pass variable to scriptblock as an argument:

```
$RestrykcjaNowa = 'Bypass'
$Komputer = '<Computername>'
$RestrykcjaZastana = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Komputer -ScriptBlock { Get-ExecutionPolicy }
$RestrykcjaZastana
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Komputer -ScriptBlock {param($RestrykcjaNowa) Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy $RestrykcjaNowa -Scope LocalMachine -Force } -ArgumentList $RestrykcjaNowa | Out-Null
```